# sql query with multiple joins

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, join

Is it possible to run inner join multiple times after `from`?
Something like:

```
select *  from (select * from A join B) T1 join (select * from C join D) T2
```

here is my query where I am getting error:

```
select * 
from ((select mf_user_email from mt_install where mf_token='iPfIefqc7IvEwq1QzoRlwnud4mOP3ATW') T1
inner join mt_interest) T2 
inner join 
(select * from mt_event_type inner join mt_event_type_name where event_type_name.mf_event_lang='he') T3
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'T2 join select * from mt_event_type inner join mt_event_type_name where mt_event' at line 1
```

Comment: You aren't using an `ON` clause for the joins

Comment: it is working on one join without `ON`

Comment: You also have a nested parenthesis problem.  Get rid of one of the left parenthesis where they are doubled, then get rid of the right parenthesis after mt_interest

Comment: Can you please post a query, I don't see any extra parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from (select mf_user_email 
      from mt_install 
      where mf_token='iPfIefqc7IvEwq1QzoRlwnud4mOP3ATW') T1
inner join mt_interest T2 
inner join 
     (select * 
      from mt_event_type 
      inner join mt_event_type_name 
      where event_type_name.mf_event_lang='he') T3
```